# How to measure raw score and convert into base rate in MCMI-III personality test?

Tags: personality, personality-disorder

I have been studying MCMI-iii test. Total 175 personality questions are present there. These questions have 2 options i.e. true or false. Based on that, person's personality get decided. Can anyone know how to calculate raw score and convert into base rate?

I have searched lot on internet, mcmi books, research paper, but formula is not given.

Any help would be appreciated.

Following is the link for reference.

[Link-1](http://images.pearsonclinical.com/images/pa/pdfs/mcmi3profile.pdf)